# class validator ignored nested object for DTO in Nest js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-validator, class-transformer

```
export class ClaimData {
  @IsString()
  @IsDefined()
  readonly network: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsDefined()
  readonly totalSupply: number;
}

export class UpdatePullStateDTO {
  @IsString()
  @IsDefined()
  @IsEnum(PullStates)
  readonly state: PullStates;

  @ValidateNested()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Type(() => ClaimData)
  @IsOptional()
  claimData?: ClaimData;
}
```

class validator ignores the claimData request body.

I enter a request like this in Postman with this body:

```
{
     "state": "completed",
     "claimData": {}
}
```

he misses it, although he should have checked the fields inside claimData.

I've read problems with this on the internet, but haven't found a solution. Even adding @ValidateNested and @Type didn't help.

Comment: you should use   @ValidateNested({ each: true })

Comment: @HaiAlison I tried it, but class-validator still misses it.

Comment: I understood the reason, the problem was due to the validation pipe that I took from the Internet, it was not made with an error. I'm sorry for disturbing you

Comment: It's not a big deal